# Facing issue while uploading the images on magento 2.4.2 Remote area

Tags: azure, permissions, magento2

I am facing an issue in magento 2 while uploading images in magento 2 backend(admin panel). Images are uploading on tmp folder under pub folder but not able to fetch the link on backend admin panel. Its working fine on my local server. Only facing the issue on server that is on remote area with IIS server on it. Any body have solution related to it. Already tried to given permission but did not work.

Comment: Just use chmod() after your upload functions..

<?php

/* 
 * All your upload code here; then pass the filename
 * and the base permissions to the chmod() below
 */

chmod($uploadedFile, 0777);

?>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom modules? Anyway, Try to redeploy static content. Connect server via SSH and goto Magento root directory. Run the following command (I prefer this way.)

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean